# Omit void as function result in C++

Tags: c++, c, void

In C/C++ there are two ways to declare a function that returns nothing.
First one is to declare a function without arguments:

```cpp
// no arguments
void f() {
}
```

The second one is to declare a function that takes `void`:

```cpp
// still no arguments
void f(void) {
}
```

However, this is not true for the function result: we can't omit `void` at the beginning of the function like this:

```cpp
// returns nothing
f() {
  return; // yay
}
```

So, is there absolutely no way to omit `void` at the beginning of the function like with the function arguments?

Comment: Um, no, not really, unless you count returning `auto`. What would be the point anyway? It's just 5 characters. Technically in C-89 you can omit a return type and it will be presumed "int", but that's not recommended. There is no implicit-int in C++. Also note that `void f()` does not define a function that takes no arguments in C, it defines a function that takes an indeterminate amount of arguments, meaning the compiler won't check whether a function call to `f` has the right number of arguments.

Comment: C or C++? They're different languages, with different rules IIRC about empty argument lists in function definitions.

Comment: At least in C, `f()` and `f(void)` are actually very different. Also, specifying the return type of functions helps with parsing, especially in the syntactical mess that is C++.

Comment: As I see you one of the warning ignorers (very very bad). If you read the warning the answer will be obvious: `<source>:4:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]

 f() {

 ^

<source>: In function 'f':

<source>:5:3: warning: 'return' with no value, in function returning non-void

   return; // yay

   ^~~~~~`

Comment: @P__J__ Only in C-89. Elsewhere it'll just be an error.

Comment: Treat warnings as errors and you will never have similar questions

Comment: @Anonymous1847 if there is an error then the problem does not exist

Comment: @Anonymous1847 didn't know about "undetermined number of arguments", thanks.

Comment: In C, i you omit the return type in a function declaration, it defaults to `int` for legacy reasons.  It's considered bad practice and should be avoided.  Similarly, if you omit the argument types (and don't declare them using archaic C syntax after the prototype), the arguments are treated as unspecified, rather than no arguments as `void` indicates.  This dates back from before C had function prototypes.

Comment: you can only do that in C89 or older. C++ doesn't allow it. Neither do newer C standards

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So, is there absolutely no way to omit void at the beginning of the function like with the function arguments?

No, there absolutely isn't. There is no function declaration syntax that doesn't have the return type in C++ nor in C99 or later. There used in C prior to C99, but the default return type would have been `int` rather than `void`.

Note that declarations `void f()` and `void f(void)` are not equivalent in C. Former declares a function with unspecified parameters while the latter declares a function with empty parameter list. In C++, both declare a function with empty parameter list.